# Shared read only memory and functions python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, shared-memory, readonly

I need to run a parallelized process on a list of inputs but using in the process all the variables and functions defined above in the code. But the process itself can be parallelized, because it depends only on one variable, the input of the list.
So I have two possibilities but I don’t know how to implement neither of the two:

1) to use a class, and have a method that should be parallelized using all the functions and attributes of that class. That is: run the method in a parallelized loop, but giving the chance to read the attributes of the object without creating a copy of it.

2) just have a big main and define global variables before running the parallelized process.

Ex:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def func(x,y,z):
    #do something 
    a = func0(x,y) #whatever function
    a = func1(a,z) #whatever function
    return a

if name==“__main__””:
   #a lot of stuff in which you create y and z
   global y,z
   result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(func)(i,y,z)for i in range(10))
```

So the problem is that when I get to the parallel function, y and z are already defined and they are just lookup data, and my question is how can I pass those values to the paralleled function, without python creating a copy for each job?

Comment: Have you heard of Threads? Or asyncio? In any case, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is `Result = Parallel()...`? What does `Parallel` refer to in your code? Also I think you misunderstand the use of `Global`. Try looking it up and take a fresh look at your problem.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile your comment is out of context. There are no variables rather then x,y,z

Comment: @Pynchia yes but my problem is how to give the function the possibility to use all the data and functions present in the memory. That is why I was thinking of classes of global variables

Comment: @Spencer so I add it in the question, Parallel comes from Joblib library. I've read about threads. I don't understand how to pass the already defined variables to different treads without copy the variables for each thread.

Comment: @M.GENTILI `Result`, before you edited the post.

Comment: @M.GENTILI Variables will stay within scope if you use threading, which seems like it would be useful for your example, so I don't think you need to worry about it. If you use multiprocessing however you'll want to use `multiprocessing.manager` module to create shared dictionaries, lists, etc. I don't think you need joblib, I'd stick to standard modules for this. If you give me a bit more to work with I'll write some code for you.

Comment: Like @Spencer, I can also try to refactor the whole program if we get enough information. Also, could you explain this: _I need to run a parallelized process on a list of inputs but using in the process all the variables and functions defined above in the code. But the process itself can be parallelized, because it depends only on one variable, the input of the list._ Don't these two sentences contradict each other, are you referring to different parts as processes?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm sorry for unclarity. What I meant is that the function is parallelizable because it can be run in parallel on the input list, but all the processes need the same lookup tables (readonly), as in the case it was (y,z)

Comment: @M.GENTILI Can you tell us a bit about the functions themselves? How computationally heavy are they? How big is the lookup table/class thingy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to pass a list to some parallel processes I would use the built in threading module. From what I can tell of your question this is all that you need, and you are able to pass arguments to the threads.

Here is a basic threading setup:

```
import threading

def func(x, y):
    print(x, y) # random example

x, y = "foo", "bar"

threads = []
for _ in range(10): # create 10 threads
    t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(x, y,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join() # waits for the thread to complete
```

However if you need to keep track of that list in a thread-safe way you will want to use a Queue:

```
import threading, queue

# build a thread-safe list
my_q = queue.Queue()
for i in range(1000):
    my_q.put(i)

# here is your worker function
def worker(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        task = queue.get() # get the next value from the queue
        print(task)
        queue.task_done() # when you are done tell the queue that this task is complete


# spin up some threads
threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(my_q,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

my_q.join() # joining the queue means your code will wait here until the queue is empty
```

Now to answer your question about shared state, you can create an object to hold your variables. That way instead of passing a copy of the variables to each thread, you can pass the object itself (I believe this is called a Borg, but I could be slightly wrong on that). When doing this if you plan on making any changes to the shared variable it is imported to ensure they are thread-safe. For example if two threads try to increment a number at the same time you could potentially lose that change as one thread overwrites the other. To prevent this we use the `threading.Lock` object. (if you do not care about this, just ignore all of the lock stuff below).

There are other ways of doing this, but I find this method to be easy to understand and extremely flexible:

```
import threading

# worker function
def worker(vars, lock):
    with lock:
        vars.counter += 1
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name}: counter = {vars.counter}")

# this holds your variables to be referenced by threads
class Vars(object):
    counter = 0
vars = Vars()

lock = threading.Lock()

# spin up some threads
threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(vars, lock, ))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: In worker function: `while not my_q.empty()` . `my_q` should be `queue` right? Also where should I run func(x,y)? BTW thanks that was helpful.

Comment: When you run the first example, (x,y) are copied in each thread, or they are just passed as pointers to the defined strings (so no extra memory for each process)

Comment: @M.GENTILI To answer your first question, yes that was my mistake. And to answer your second question x and y are copied. If you want to keep them as a pointer check out the python Manager object.

Comment: @M.GENTILI Actually you can set up something called a Borg, which is kind of cool. I'll edit my code in a bit with a new example.

Comment: @M.GENTILI Ok I added an example of sharing state. If you use multiprocessing you would use a Manager, but for threading this is a very handy way of solving this problem. Don't be afraid to Accept and up-vote if I have answered your question ;)

Comment: If OP is doing anything other than IO they should be using processes though, not threads, right?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Not necessarily. For the most part you are right, but there are plenty of times you would be able to use threads instead of processes. Processes get a lot more complex so I try to stick to threads where possible (for example creating background operations that do not freeze the UI). Without knowing what work he is actually trying to do I cannot really say.

Comment: @Spencer I'm interested by the idea that _processes get a lot more complex_. I was under the impression that it isn't necessarily the case in Python. The multiprocessing docs even state _multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the threading module._ I do agree with your point overall though, I wish OP would be specific.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It entirely depends what you are doing. In a simple case you can literally replace your imports to switch from threading to processing. However in the real world I found it to be more complex. The reason is that threads share memory, but processes do not - so in order to get data in/out of a subprocess you need to pickle that data and manage it carefully (hence the Manager module from multiprocessing). It is also easy to lose track of what exactly the software is doing and becomes harder to debug. Even exceptions can sometimes go uncaught, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile If I get a moment today I'll throw up a multiprocessing example using a Manager. Then maybe M. GENTILI will finally accept my answer ;)

Comment: sorry for late acceptance. Thank you all for the useful tips :)

Comment: last question. When threads are joined the have the same order of the input list?

Comment: @M.GENTILI Sorry I don't fully understand your question... Joining them just makes your code halt until they complete, it does not effect the input at all. For example putting a print statement after the join will cause your program to only print once all of the threads have completed and shut down.